# How to push application code to Amazon EC2 servers in autoscaling mode, via Jenkins?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have an environment in AWS where EC2 instances are in autoscaling mode, i.e. new instances spin up as per the load on deployed instances.

Now, if I want to integrate this environment with Jenkins, how can I push my codes from Github to these EC2 instances, where my application is deployed. And with every change in my code version, Github should invoke EC2 instances to have the same versions deployed, and also every new instances should be created with this updated version of code, i.e. every autoscaled instances must have the same code version running. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have an executable version of your latest code on a deploy server. You can do this by forcing Jenkins to deploy your code when a new commit is made on a specific branch in GitHub. Then all you need is an AMI for your Auto Scaling Group that has a job/task which runs let's say every 5 minutes (based on how long one single task takes). This job/task fetches (copies) the code from the deploy server and then starts the application. As an example, in Windows Task Scheduler you can add two actions to a task: one for updating (e.g. a simple robocopy) the code and one for running the app.